# How to wrap a list of pointers to abstract class?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, abstract-class, smart-pointers

I try to wrap a list of smart pointers to abstract class (`list<shared_ptr<Base>> list_`) into some classes (`Item`, `Drawer`, `Box`). Then in the main function, I have a `map` of `Box`'es and it doesn't work. I  found a way around and I can use `new` but I suspect that it just causes bugs which I can't see. How to make it work? Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    virtual int get() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(int x) { x_ = x; }
    int get() override { return x_; }
private:
    int x_;
};

class Item {
public:
    Item() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            list_.push_back(make_shared<Derived>(i));
        }
    }
    list<shared_ptr<Base>>& get_list() { return list_; }
private:
    list<shared_ptr<Base>> list_;
};

class Drawer {
public:
    Drawer(Item& item) : item_(item) {}
    void Draw() {
        list<shared_ptr<Base>>& list = item_.get_list();
        cout << list.size() << ":  ";
        while (!list.empty()) {
            shared_ptr<Base> pointer = dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(list.front());
            cout << pointer->get() << " ";
            list.pop_front();
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
private:
    Item& item_;
};

class Box {
public:
    Box() : drawer_(item_) {}
    void Draw() { drawer_.Draw(); }
private:
    Item item_;
    Drawer drawer_;
};

int main() {
    Box box;
    box.Draw();

    map<int, Box> boxes;                                // it doesn't work, why?
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        boxes.insert(std::pair<int, Box>(i, Box()));
    }
    for (auto& b : boxes) { b.second.Draw(); }

    map<int, Box*> pointers;                            // it does work, why?
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        pointers.insert(std::pair<int, Box*>(i, new Box()));
    }
    for (auto& b : pointers) {  b.second->Draw(); }
    for (auto& b : pointers) {  delete b.second; }
}
```

And here is the result:

```
10:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
0:
0:
0:
10:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
10:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
10:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Address sanitizer is your friend. It shows immediately that the program is doing something wacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line here

```
boxes.insert(std::pair<int, Box>(i, Box()));
```

You are creating a temporary `Box` object in your pair, which is moved into the map.

Let's call them `Box1`, the temporary that is created, and `Box2`, the move-constructed object inside the map.

When `Box1` is created it correctly has a drawer which refers to the item in `Box1`.

When we then move it into the map, we get `Box2` that has a drawer that still refers to the item in `Box1`.

When we then go on

```
for (auto& b : boxes) { b.second.Draw(); }
```

`Box1` has already been destroyed and doesn't exist anymore. So when we try to use the reference to it we are using a dangling reference which is UB. In this case you get the result of 0, but you could equally get a crash or any random output.

To fix it we can add a copy constructor to `Box` to deal with this.

```
class Box {
public:
    Box() : drawer_(item_) {}
    Box(const Box& other) : item_(other.item_), drawer_(item_) {}
    void Draw() { drawer_.Draw(); }
private:
    Item item_;
    Drawer drawer_;
};
```

Now the drawer of the copy will refer to the right item.

As to why the version with pointers work, it since we are copying the pointer, so the same object remains until it's deleted. There is no object moved or copied, only the pointer is copied, and a copied pointer still refers to the right object.

Comment: Well spotted. `Box` contains two subobjects and one references the other. It is always a bad idea. Perhaps a better solution is to get rid of `Box::item_` and make `Drawer` contain an item by value.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Yes, I'm not sure what the best design choice is for OP. But eliminating the problem completely by design would be the best thing. This can get a bit fragile to maintain over time.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Box() : drawer_(Drawer(item_)) {}
```

You have created a `Drawer(item_)` object and then calling the copy constructor for `drawer_()`. A default copy constructor doesn't always handle complex data structures.

Try

```
Box() : drawer_(item_) {}
```

to call the normal constructor for `Drawer`

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question. Unfortunately, it doesn't help.

Comment: The compiler-generated copy constructor for `Drawer` works just fine.